# How to add a specific item innerText when click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a simple shopping cart. I want to add the whole item to the cart when clicking the add button. The item looks like this (there are 6 with different name and prices

For now I'm working on adding to the cart just the name (I will use the same process for the price), but when I click the add button it adds the name of the last item and not the one I'm clicking. How do I fix this?

```js
const cart = document.querySelector(".cart");
const productName = document.querySelectorAll(".product-name");
const productPrice = document.querySelector(".product-price");

const addBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".add");
addBtn.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", addToCart);
})

//Add to cart
function addToCart(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Create DIV
  const item = document.createElement("div");
  item.classList.add("item");
  //Add name
  const name = document.createElement("h2");
  name.classList.add("product-name");
  productName.forEach(productN => {
    name.innerText = productN.innerText;
  })
  item.appendChild(name);
  cart.appendChild(item);
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <h2 class="product-name">Beer</h2>
  <h3 class="product-price">$4</h3>
  <button class="add">Add to cart</button>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <h2 class="product-name">Burger</h2>
  <h3 class="product-price">$12</h3>
  <button class="add">Add to cart</button>
 </div>

<section class="section">
        <h2 class="text-center">Cart</h2>
        <div class="cart"></div>
    </section>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It gives console errors. Please update the snippet with relevant HTML

Comment: `productName.forEach(productN => {
    name.innerText = productN.innerText;
  })` loops and replaces the innerText each time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely want this

```js
const cart = document.getElementById("cart");
const productName = document.querySelectorAll(".product-name");
const productPrice = document.querySelector(".product-price");

const addBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".add");
addBtn.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", addToCart);
})

//Add to cart
function addToCart(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Create DIV
  const item = document.createElement("div");
  item.classList.add("item");
  //Add name
  const name = document.createElement("h2");
  name.classList.add("product-name");
  name.innerText = e.target.parentNode.querySelector(".product-name").innerText;
 
  item.appendChild(name);
  cart.appendChild(item);
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <h2 class="product-name">Beer</h2>
  <h3 class="product-price">$4</h3>
  <button class="add">Add to cart</button>
</div>

<div id="cart"></div>
```

Delegate the click from the products

```js
const cart = document.getElementById("cart");
const products = document.getElementById("products");

const productName = document.querySelectorAll(".product-name");
const productPrice = document.querySelector(".product-price");

products.addEventListener("click", addToCart);


//Add to cart
function addToCart(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.classList.contains("add")) return; // not a button
  const parent = tgt.parentNode;
  //Create DIV
  const item = document.createElement("div");
  item.classList.add("item");
  //Add name
  const name = document.createElement("h2");
  name.classList.add("product-name");
  name.innerText = parent.querySelector(".product-name").innerText;
  item.appendChild(name);
  cart.appendChild(item);
}
```

```html
<div id="products">
  <div class=" product ">
    <h2 class="product-name ">Beer</h2>
    <h3 class="product-price ">$4</h3>
    <button class="add ">Add to cart</button>
  </div>
  <div class="product ">
    <h2 class="product-name ">Wine</h2>
    <h3 class="product-price ">$4</h3>
    <button class="add ">Add to cart</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="cart"></div>
```